# how to increase index max result window in Elasticsearch for a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

elasticsearch return this error when trying to access more than 10,000 records in my rails application

```
[500] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_phase_execution_exception","reason":"Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [12270].
```

based on my search I know that there are some solutions

1. increase index max result window
2. use search_after

and I couldn't find a tutorial that would properly set any of them on a rails application, so can you help me doing this ?, knowing that I'm using will_paginate gem for pagination, and I want to know if I change it to pagy gem, would it solve the problem, or this error doesn't have a thing to do with the pagination ?

Comment: Try with Scroll API

Comment: not ideal with multiple requests at the same time

Answer (score 0):

This is an index setting. Update it by executing 
Curl as shown below

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_settings" -d '{ "index" : { "max_result_window" : 1000000 } }'